# Is there a graphical bootloader like rEFInd but for a computer with BIOS (not UEFI)?

Tags: bootloader, bios, refind

I want to have a bootloader like rEFInd, but my computer has BIOS and not UEFI because it is a bit old (+7 years). Is there a graphical bootloader like rEFInd for BIOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that for my personal interests, I can install a Grub theme and go with it, because there are some really good themes that have nothing to envy from rEFInd themes.

Apart from BURG which hasn't been updated since 2014 or so, I haven't found any other options to have a graphical bootloader, so I will stick to Grub for now.